# Fullwidth background to the left

Tags: css

Anyone who know how I write the css to get the background to be under left menu and than go out to the left; full width.
Back in the old days you could do this with frameset, but how about nowadays?

[image]

```
.currentpage-category {
    main {
        padding: 0;
    }

    #categoryWithSidemenu{
        background: rgb(31,57,87);
        background: linear-gradient(163deg, rgba(31,57,87,1) 0%, rgba(94,106,120,1) 100%); 
        background-size: 30% 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 100vw;
        margin-left: calc((100% - 100vw) / 2);  
        .categoryContainer {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 20px 0 200px 0;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            max-width: 1426px;
        }
    }

    #categoryWithoutSidemenu {
        padding: 100px 15px 120px;
    }

}
```

This is what I have tried, but the "background-size" above doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share your HTML as well?

Comment: What do you mean with `under left menu and than go out to the left` ... how should that look like? Please update your code to include CSS, not SCSS. Also add the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for reply, but I found a solution by my self.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0Fh0.jpg

```
.currentpage-category {
    main {
        padding: 0;
    }
    #categoryWithSidemenu > * {
        margin: 0;
    } 

    #categoryWithSidemenu{
        background-color: #1d2e42;
        width: 100vw;
        margin-left: calc((100% - 100vw) / 2);  
        .categoryContainer {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0px 0 0px 0;
            max-width: 1426px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 2;
            &:after {
                content: " ";
                display: block;
                clear: both;
            }
            .sidebar {
                width: 200px;
                float: left;
                min-height: 600px;
            }
            .side-content {
                background: #1d2e42;
                padding: 20px 20px 100px;
            }
        }
        &:before {
            content: " ";
            z-index: 1;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 650px;
            background: rgb(31,57,87);
            background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(31,57,87,1) 0%, rgba(94,106,120,1) 100%);
            width: 50%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    }
```